# Reset the state of other component onClick using MUI in React

Tags: reactjs, notifications, material-ui, react-hooks, state

I am trying to reset the number of the badge component once somebody clicks on it. Right now the number comes from the dummyData (which is an array of objects) So ideally it would be great to reset that number every time someone clicks on it. I am using material design UI components.

```
export const sampleContent = () => {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

    const handleOpen = (e) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = (e) => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <IconButton color="primary">
                <Badge
                    badgeContent={dummyData.length}
                    color="error"
                >
                    <NotificationsIcon
                        onClick={handleOpen}
                    />
                </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
                id="simple-menu"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                keepMounted
                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                onClose={handleClose}
            >
                <MenuList>
                    <MenuItem
                        onClick={handleClose}
                    >
                        <p>Title</p>
                        <p>Description</p>
                    </MenuItem>
                 </MenuList>
            </Menu>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to handle this.  Ideally you would probably pass in the data to use.  For example, have `SampleContent` accept a callback whenever the badge is clicked, then update the parent state and pass a new `dummyData` array into `SampleContent`.  Alternatively, you could just use local state and reset the state on click.  Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-architecture-c48bt?file=/src/App.js) based on your code.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Badge, IconButton, Menu, MenuItem, MenuList } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Notifications as NotificationsIcon } from "@material-ui/icons";

const SampleContent = ({ dummyData }) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = React.useState(dummyData.length);

  const handleOpen = e => {
    setAlerts(0);
    setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = e => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton color="primary">
        <Badge badgeContent={alerts} color="error">
          <NotificationsIcon onClick={handleOpen} />
        </Badge>
      </IconButton>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuList>
          <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
            <p>Title</p>
            <p>Description</p>
          </MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <SampleContent dummyData={[1, 2, 3]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope that helps!